# Requesting a PHP script via AJAX. The AJAX request returns actual PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, json

Requesting JSON from php script :

```
var channelList;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({    
        url: 'channellookup.php',    
        dataType: 'json',    
        error: function(){console.log(arguments)},     
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.success);
            channelList = data;
        }  
    });
});
```

Now to the interesting part: The error message in the console reads like this:

```
Arguments { 0: XMLHttpRequest, 1: "parsererror", 2: "Invalid JSON: <?php
   header('Content-type: application/json');     // To ensure output json type.
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
```

And so on. **My whole PHP code is in that message.** Something must go completely wrong here.

Here is my PHP in full

```
<?php

   header('Content-type: application/json');     // To ensure output json type.
   class MyDB extends SQLite3

   {
      function __construct()

      {
         $this->open('database_sqlite3.db');    
      }
   }

   $db = new MyDB();

   if(!$db){    
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();    
   } else {    
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";    
   }

   $sql =<<<EOF

      SELECT * from channels;

EOF;

   $ret = $db->query($sql);

   $channelList = array();

   while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){    
      $channelList[] = $row;    
   }
   echo json_encode($channelList);
   $db->close();
?>
```

as you can see I do encode as json. As I said this works in the terminal.
Please keep in mind that I do not want to use the json in my html yet so the page generating before the asynchronous request is completed isn't an issue yet.

Is the problem maybe that I am not doing this on a remote server but on local files? As I understand the Browser should be able to handle this case.

Comment: remove `header('Content-type: application/json');` from your php file and check again

Comment: the result is still the same

Comment: are you sure your php file is on a server that can run php?

Comment: what do you get if you go to channellookup.php directly in web browser?

Comment: it's on my local machine. I also have a server running but maybe it's configurated wrongly, I'll check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that your PHP didn't compile at all. This is because the result that was returned, is in fact the `body` of your php file, indicating that no translation took place.

You can check if your PHP instance is running by creating a file with the code:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

And use your browser to navigate to that page and see if there are any output. You want to check your PHP/Apache installation until the output is correct.

As to why your webtool work, I cannot phantom any reason. It should fail in the same way.

Comment: Well I simply checked the string generated by terminal `$ php channellookup.php` and it was valid. I suppose my webserver doesn't serve the request. As I understand the browsers are able to handle the xmlhttprequests but of course not the PHP itself. I'll check my server configuration. The server is the same machine I am developing on.

Comment: You are incorrectly concluding that just because you have `$php` in shell, means that your server is binded to that module and will hence parse it. When you do `$php channellookup.php`, you are parsing the code. Hence it runs and returns your data. However when you make a web request from the browser, it needs to go to a server, like Apache, which then decides whether the file you have requested for (typically by file extension, in this case `*.*php`) requires to be parsed, and then parse it. Otherwise, your browser request can NEVER access the shell `$php` module.

Comment: Also, make the changes as described by @Joerg.

Comment: Yes I did have apache running but perhaps I configured something wrong.
I reinstalled the server and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After you send the header, you are echoing the connection status from the db.

Remove this lines:

```
    if(!$db){    
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();    
   } else {    
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";    
   }
```

And put the header above the JSON output:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');   
echo json_encode($channelList);
$db->close();
```

Comment: you're right of course. this code was taken from a tutorial and there was also a success message after the echo. I edited that but forgot to edit out the part you mentioned